# How to use the flags of send() syscall?

Tags: c++, send, system-calls

I'm looking for a way to use send with the ENOTCONN flag but the compiler says ENOTCONN was not declared in this scope.

I know I should include  and  but I don't know how to do it in c++.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `while (*title) { *title = tolower(*title++); }`, please.

Comment: "I know i should include and but i don't know how to do it in c++." `#include <filename>`/`#include "filename"`. If that's not what you mean, can you add more detail to the question?

Answer (score 0):

I guess ENOTCONN is an error code, not a flag for send(). What exactly you want to achieve?